# Facebook thumbnail image wrong, altough right in Object Debugger

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, thumbnails, facebook-opengraph

When I share the following site on Facebook: http://fuuuu.net/scientific-thoughts/
I get a false thumnail image. However when I check with the Object Debugger the preview looks like it should.

(The image without text is the right one)

Thanks for your help,
Michael

Comment: You have specified 3 og:image. If you don't want all of them to be used don't specify all of them

Comment: Actually I want these. The one without text should be the first one. In the debugger the preview is correct, but when I share the site the right one is just the 3rd one.

Comment: Yes if you specify 3 we will use any of them. Why do you want all 3 if you don't want all 3 to be displayed

Comment: So that the user gets a little selection. You choose them random? And it is the default of the SEO by Yoast plugin(wordpress)

Comment: I bet is not is random.

Comment: So the only way to be sure is to have only one og:image?

Comment: Yes. That is the only solution

Comment: Strange. But thanks! Maybe someone else knows how to set multiple og:image tags but with the ability to define the first one

Answer (score 0):

Try to upload the image immediately under it (with the rails) and if that one shows right than it is the way the image was saved with your image editor.
Just reopen and save it as .jpg making sure the horizontal and vertical sides are properly defined.

Comment: Sry. I don't understand what you mean. Can you explain further?

Comment: When you process an image some editors don't save correctly all the settings of the image (like landscape or portrait). That might cause your image to not be read properly by your browser.

Comment: Thats not the problem here. I set an image via open graph so its the one which gets shared. When I check with the FB object debugger it looks right. However, when I share it the right pictures is just the 3rd one.

Answer (score 0):

How does it work when you use different browsers? Is it the same thing?